# zip() function doesn´t work in R Studio: How can I create a compressed file .zip with password?

Tags: r, zip, compression, gzip

I want to create a compressed file .zip with password in R Studio, but the function zip() from utils doesn´t work. The function doesn´t give me an error message or warning message and It doesn't do anything. I´m trying to compress a .csv file. Below, there is an reproducible example:

```
datos <- data.frame(A=1:100, B=1:100, D= rep("a",times=100))
                  
write.csv(datos, file = "datos.csv")

password <- "hdye89"
               
zip("datos.zip", "datos.csv", flags= paste0("-P", password))
```

Here is my session info

[image]

[image]

I researched and found that I can generate a compressed file with gzip () and it works for me, but I don't know how I can enter the password? Can 7zip.exe be used to do password compression?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: It created a password protected file on my system. Are you sure you know where Rstudio is putting your output? If you are sure about that, are you sure you know what parameters should be passed to your system version of `zip`? You can find which version is being used by `Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD",  "zip")`

Comment: Yes, am sure where R studio is putting the output, but zip doesn´t create the compressed file. Like zip if a function of utils, the version is the same that the version of utils, in my case 4.0.4

Comment: The zip function in R is actually a wrapper for your system functin, what ever that might be. I showed you how to determine what that function is. You should be using [edit] to clarify the problem. Failing to do that will likely result in the question being closed as "not a reproducible problem".

Comment: Do you have the `zip` utility on your path for your computer? Can you create a zip from the command line?

Comment: With the zip function of utils it will not generate anything, neither zip without password nor zip with password. But if I use the zip function of the zip package (zip :: zip ("datos.zip", "datos.csv")) it generates the zip file in my directory, but I have not found how to put the password in that package.

Comment: Do you really want the argument to zip to be "-Phdye89" or should it be "-P hydye89"?